# Many to many through: Going from Associations::CollectionProxy to AssociationRelation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a many to many through relationship with users favoriting clients (Through favorites.rb) and I want to know how to turn a CollectionProxy into an AssociationRelation, so I can get a relation with all the clients that are the users' favorites.

Or just simply, how to get them all in a AssociationRelation - doesn't have to be turned into from the CollectionProxy.

**EDIT:** What I'm looking for is simply a relation that lists all the clients. I realize I asked the question differently. **How do I get a relation with all the clients?** - Not a relation with the favorite_id, user_id, etc - I want a relation purely with the clients, and their rows.

I can find the CollectionProxy like this:

```
user = User.last
user.favorites    # Gives me a CollectionProxy
```

But how do I find the favorite clients as an AssociationRelation?

Models:

user.rb:

```
has_many :favorites, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :clients, through: 'favorites'
```

Client.rb

```
has_many :favorites, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :users, through: 'favorites'
```

Favorite.rb

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :client
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can operate on [`ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html) as you would normally do on [`ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AssociationRelation.html).

But if you really want to have the latter, just call, for example, `all`:

```
user.favorites.all.class #=> Client::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation
```

> How do I get a relation with all the clients?

You have defined the association:

```
has_many :clients, through: 'favorites'
```

Thus getting a relation of associated `clients` is as easy as:

```
user.clients
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked turning it into a relation! But maybe I wasnt precise in my question (edited again): What I'm looking for is a relation where i list all the clients from the favorite collection. Is there a way to get a relation with only the clients in it? Not with the favorite_id, just the clients. This get me a relation with the favorite_ids.

Comment: @sneglefar `user.clients` is what you're looking for.

Comment: But user.clients gives me a CollectionProxy? user.clients.count then gives me 0. Is there a way to do user.clients and list them all in a relation? And thanks!

Comment: It has to be said that I've been using favorites.rb before for a polymorphic association, that didn't work out. Maybe I should try and destroy the whole model, and build it again, since I believe this could be messing with the ability to call user.clients - And thank you so much, its really helpful

Comment: @sneglefar yea, I think if this is not working as it should (because it should), than something might be wrong with the `schema.rb`. Can't help you without seeing it, but rolling back the migrations and rebuilding it without polymorphism might work...

Comment: I basically have a user.role = vendor and a user.role = user - Now I realize that I allow both: has_many :users, through: 'favorites for normal users to favorite clients, but also in user.rb I have belongs_to :user, for the vendors to own a client. But I want to have both and also the normal users to have favorites and still be able to find a normal users' favorite clients like with user.clients. Is there any way to have both and accomplish what I'm trying to?

Comment: Since it's a bit late/complex to split the user model into a vendor user and a normal user model, is there a more advanced query I could do instead of users.clients to get all the favorites?

Comment: @sneglefar to get all favorites of all users you would do the following: `Client.includes(:users).where("users.role = 'user' AND users.id IS NOT NULL")`

Comment: Sort of like: favorite_ids = user.favorites.ids to give an array with the ids.. then using the array to find the clients with those id's.. like: Client.find(id: favorite_ids) ... I know this is very close.. but it gives me this error: Couldn't find Client with 'id'={:id=>[430, 431, 432, 433]} - So how can I escape the hash, to insert a pure array?

Comment: @sneglefar `find` returns the first found record, but you want to get a collection of records, thus you need `where`: `Client.where(id: favorite_ids)`.

Comment: This did the job!: collected = user.favorites.collect(&:client_id) to get a pure array with ids (no hash-stuff in it).. Then I put them all into a where query like this: clients = Client.where(id: collected).. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: @Hint: use `user.favorites.pluck(:client_id)` for most efficient SQL query instead of Ruby processing :)

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to sort by my ids-array in the newly created .where query ? - As of now it finds all the clients by id, but it throws away the sorting order of the array. Any ideas on how to solve that or what to google/search for?

Comment: @sneglefar ActiveRecord always return the collection in the order of primary key, `id`. Thus it does not matter, in what order you pass the  `favorite_ids`, the returned collection will always be "sorted" against SQL rules.

Comment: Thanks. Could I somehow do a hack on that collection ordering them by my array of ids? Sort of like clients.sort_by(id: collected)

Comment: @sneglefar here's the Ruby version for that: `favorite_ids.each_with_object([]) { |id, array| array << Client.find(id) }`. The probjem, is that will return an Array, not AR::Collection

Comment: To turn that into an AR I think it can be done like this: array = collected.each_with_object([]) { |id, array| array << Client.find(id) } and then turn that array into an AR like this: Client.where(id: array.map(&:id) 

Great! So the ruby version works. Wish I somehow knew the rails version..

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter much that it's an array to me, as long as its ordered. If anyone out there sees this, and knows the rails version, please don't hesitate to help out :) - I'll be forever grateful after spending days on this!

Comment: And to reiterate what Andrey said, my way of mapping them into an AR did not work. It creates an AR but throws the order out the window

Comment: Holy moly, I got it working by using the great order_as_specified gem! 
For anyone interested:
First do: favorites_collect_the_ids_in_array = user.favorites.pluck(:client_id)
... then do: ar_of_all_favorites = Client.order_as_specified(id: favorites_collect_the_ids_in_array).where(id: favorites_collect_the_ids_in_array)

Answer (score 0):

The great gem order_as_specified can do this in an easy manner!

1:

```
@favorites_collect_the_ids_in_array = @user.favorites.pluck(:client_id)
```

... then:

2:

```
@ar_of_all_favorites = Client.order_as_specified(id:  @favorites_collect_the_ids_in_array).where(id: @favorites_collect_the_ids_in_array)
```