# How to turn array of numbers into clients-array or AR with clients?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I have this:

```
collectedclientids = user.favorites.pluck(:client_id)
```

and it gives me this:

```
=> [18, 34, 1, 90]
```

Now, I want to fetch clients in the **exact same order** and have an array with them, or an ActiveRelation.

It'd be similar in ruby to do this:

```
clientsordered = collectedclientids.each_with_object([]) { |id, array| array << Client.find(id) }
```

.. which gives me an array of the clients in the same order with client_id [18, 34, 1, 90]

**But how can I accomplish this in rails? Any ideas on methods to use?**

Comment: In the linked question there are answers for two major databases: [postgresql](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33651683/1772830) and [mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1685784/1772830)

Comment: @AndreyDeineko I don't think this is a duplicate. The problem should be solved by using a `through` relationship on the `Favourite` object. That is, within `User`, there should be `has_many :clients, through: :favourites`. With that in place @sneglefar will be able to do `user.clients` and `user.clients.pluck(:id)`

Comment: @ReggieB [OP already has this setup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41975930/many-to-many-through-going-from-associationscollectionproxy-to-associationrel), but it is (at least that's what he claims) somehow broken.

Comment: OK - then I agree - this is a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks Andrey. It is a duplicate in that case. The original thread, suggests 3 things: 1) To get them as an array (not AR),  2 ) To get an AR, based on an advanced scope I do myself and 3 ) using a gem called order_as_specified. 

I have now tried 1 and 3, and 3 doesn't work for me (Rails 5). 1 works, and I can get an array, but I want an AR. I've also tried a bit with scopes (2) in Rails 5, but it seems as if scopes in rails 5 are not the way to go? Any other ways or easier explained ways to get an AR with the clients? (An easier explanation of 2)